# iOS How to perform http GET request over and over in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, http, afnetworking

I am developing an iOS app that need to perform HTTP GET request to get JSON file every 10 seconds in the background.

I am using AFNetworking and I have already created a subclass of AFHTTPClient. Now it can get the JSON via HTTP GET request successfully, but I don't know how to let the HTTPClient get the JSON over and over in the background. My app need to update its UI with the information in the JSON.

Comment: Use an `NSTimer`? Or Use `dispatch_after` to queue up the next call after one completes.

Comment: NSTimer works,thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **NSTimer**

```
timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(CallWebServiceMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

and you can stop this by

```
 [myTimer invalidate];
```

also read the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html